# Where to host code for small, individual projects?

Tags: open-source, software-distribution

as the final project for a programming course I took I've made a small tool which deals with databases issues. It works and I think it could be useful to others, so I'd like to put the code on the net to see if it actually is.
I'm aware of various source code hosts such as GitHub or Google Code, however they seem more oriented towards group development and I'm not sure if they're good for individual complete projects as well. I'm not saying I'm opposed to collaboration, but those platforms just seem a bit too much for something so simple.
Does anyone have any idea on how I should share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github would be fine - just because git allows multiple developers on a project doesn't mean it is required.

Most of the complexity is there if you need it but you do not have to ever visit those screens.  The last time I looked at the network view for my more complex projects was a long time ago!